# How do i get rich controls in PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

How do i get rich controls like tree, calendar etc in PHP? PHP by default doesn't include any such controls. I am planning to use either CakePHP or Zend framework as i heard from my friends that these two are really nice frameworks. Do these frameworks include support for tree and such controls? I actually come from Asp.Net and JSF background. So i am not very much aware of PHP.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

These controls don't belong to PHP, they belong more to HTML and JavaScript, since it's part of user interface.

You can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to display and control these rich controls, however you'll need to write the PHP code that can use them separately (PHP-generated HTML and JS).

For tree you can use [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/), since jQuery UI doesn't have this control yet.

Comment: Hi tomp, i know we can use only html controls but are there no options except using JQuery and fiddling with javascript? Any library which is built on top of JQuery and can be used in PHP?

Comment: @Nitesh Panchal: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any library that would do that, maybe others will help you.

Maybe you could find some code snippets, e.g. for Zend framework (Zend_Form), from users of the framework.

Comment: I was going to post the same, but it's not *entirely* true any more: Both Zend and (I think) Cake integrate client-side controls to some extent.